# How to get accountId where Lambda deployed to programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like get accountId of AWS account where Lambda is deployed to.

Will [boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account']](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) return lambda's account of deployment itself, or account of lambda caller?

What is the correct way of getting Lambda AWS accountId inside its own code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lambda runs are invoked with a set of environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, etc, which are the same as would result from a direct call to sts.assume_role() assuming the role specified in the configuration of the lambda function.  If you look at the full output of `get_caller_identity()` you see the `Arn` field is the normal arn-of-role-slash-name-of-entity-assuming-the-role.  So I presume that the value of the `Account` field is technically the account owning *the IAM Role* that's being assumed, but since (AFAIK?) that has to be from the same account as the lambda function itself, I think that's a reliable indicator of the account of the lambda function.

Personally, I set an `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` environment variable on most/all of my lambda functions, which is really easy to pass through in CloudFormation as `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: { Ref: "AWS::AccountId" }`.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get it from the context:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    aws_account_id = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[4]
    print(aws_account_id)
```

If you are interested in how it works you can read [this](https://www.radishlogic.com/aws/lambda/how-to-get-the-aws-account-id-in-lambda-python/)